# How to configure Seaside 3.2 session timeouts (age)

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

when starting my image with Seaside app, I have this code in startup method:

```
WAMySeasideApp>>startUp: resuming 
        WAMySeasideApp waApplication
                preferenceAt: #maximumRelativeAge
                put: 18000. "5 hours"
        WAEFTTasksApp waApplication
                preferenceAt: #maximumAbsoluteAge
                put: 86400. "24 hours"
        ZnZincServerAdaptor startOn: 8080.

WAMySeasideApp>>waApplication
        ^ WAAdmin defaultDispatcher handlerAt: 'my-seaside-app'
```

This "maximum age" session parameters are correctly showing in seaside config web app, but every seaside session is still 30 minutes.

What is proper way to configure session timeouts (age), dynamically, via code? For Seaside 3.2 please.

Comment: maybe you can recreate the cache after changing the values: WAMySeasideApp waApplication
                preferenceAt: #maximumRelativeAge
                put: 18000; createCache.

Comment: calling createCache is not enough, we need to assign the new cache: WAMySeasideApp waApplication cache:  WAMySeasideApp waApplication createCache.

Comment: That's it! Thanks! But some convenience

Comment: ...but some convenience method will be good (resetPrefsCace or somethig like this).

Comment: We do app cache: app createCache in order to make the changes effective.
+1 for the convenience method.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
anApplication cache expiryPolicy configuration 
at: #cacheTimeout put: 1200
```

(from http://book.seaside.st, 18.5 Catching the Session Expiry Notification)

Comment: Unfortunately not. Seaside book is outdated and there is no "expiryPolicy" method at all in Seaside 3.2. This is for older Seaside versions...

Comment: Ah, thats the reason I didn't found anything about maximumRelativeAge/maximumAbsoluteAge. I only looked at seaside 3.1